# Iphone application build error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I am using XCODE 3.2.5 and getting following error while compiling the code

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Here are my settings:
C/C++ compiler version -- LLVM compiler 1.6
Base SDK - 4.2
IOS deployment target - 4.2

What could be wrong here?

Comment: have you tried using GCC 4.2 compiler instead?

Comment: try cleaning everything then retrying.. don't know what else could cause something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with compiler. It should by GCC for IOS and LLVM for MAC.